# Python cannot create subfolder by set folder name as input

Tags: python, directory

I want to create folder name 1 in folder abc. This is the code.

```
id=input("enter user id : ")

path = "/abc/" + str(id)

try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

I enter 1 for create folder name 1 but it show error like this. How to fix it?

```
enter user id : 1
Creation of the directory /abc/1 failed
```

Comment: Apparently, an `OSError` exception is raised - look at the exception and see what message or error code comes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
id = input("enter user id : ")
path = "abc/{}".format(id)
try:
    file = open(path)
except Exception:
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
```

This will create the folder if the folder will not exist.

and try to create the path of the file like this:

```
path = os.path.join('os.chdir()','abc','id)
```

using os.path.join is a better practice.